# AWS s3 accessing private data

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have stored data in the aws bucket using ACL private. So can i get the data back from third party app. I couldn't find any help on the documentation. Any example will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your AWS config set up by following this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-configuring.html

Then make sure permissions are set that correspond to that AWS config: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#permissions

Comment: So if i give read permission can i get the file through node.js using the link for private

Comment: Yes if you configure AWS for Node as per that guide.